Masters in pure mathematics at a college in us/uk
So,
I am a final (5th) year integrated msc mathematics student at National Institute Of Technology, Surat. I aspire to do a masters in pure mathematics before finally doing a phd. I am pretty clear about my goal.
My college is not reputed in mathematics specially pure mathematics. It doesn’t even have graduate courses like algebraic geometry, algebraic number theory etc.. I have performed somewhat well in the past 4 years and have a CGPA of 8.6/10 with much better grade in pure math courses like number theory, complex analysis etc. Since I am interested in number theory, I have done two internships one in some topics in analytical number theory like dirichlet’s theorem and arithmetic functions and the other in p-Adic numbers and Automorphic forms. I have some experience in undergraduate math competitions (even winning a diploma in one of them). But I feel like I won’t make it into any top math phd programs in us, uk or any other places, because I am guessing they obviously require much more.
Now currently I am very interested in studying algebraic number theory and local fields and am currently studying Cassels book.
I need some serious advice on what I should do? The application fees is huge for every college.
What I really want to ask is, Looking at these things do I have any shot at getting into mathematics masters programs in colleges like imperial, Kings, Nottingham or other colleges at similar level to these? Any advice would be helpful.

I don't think that it is possible to answer without knowing a lot more background. But you also need to ask yourself how you are to finance this: if the application fee (about £100) is "huge", what about the course fee (about £35,000 p.a.) and living/travel costs?
